# Creating a specific symbolic link

Tags: windows-7

I need to know the command line for creating a symbolic link to the following folder: `F:\screenshots\games`.

The game is located in `C:\users\public\games` and the name of the symbolic link `Pictures`.

What would the command line be?

Answer (score 0):

Use `mklink`

`mklink [[/d] | [/h] | [/j]] <Link> <Target>`

```
/D – used to create symbolic links for directories (d for directory)
/H – used to create hard links (h for hard link)
/J – used to create directory junction (j for junction)
Link - specifies the new symbolic link name.
Target - specifies the path (relative or absolute) that the new link
         refers to.
```

In your case, `cd` to `C:\users\public\games`, then:

`MKlink /D Pictures F:\screenshots\games`

Comment: Thank you, I was dropping a space and just couldn't see it.