# Frequently clearing Windows temp folder causes problems with some apps

Tags: windows, temporary-files

I use Radeon RAMDisk for my temp folder on Windows 7. I like to frequently clear the temp folder, so I have the Radeon RAMDisk software set to not save upon reboot, so each time I restart my compute I have a completely clear temp folder. I also changed the environmental variables for the temp folders so everything points to my ramdisk.

I am having some problems with Box.com sync and Microsoft OneDrive. After each reboot I need to enter my username and password for those again. This is annoying and the developers behind those 2 pieces of software should know better than to use the temp folder to store the authentication like that. I don't have a problem with Dropbox or MEGA...

However, one problem I am having is I cannot seem to find any files relating to OneDrive or Box in the temp folder even after I log in again.

Just to be clear, OneDrive asks for username and password, but Box.com remembers my username and I only have to reenter the password

Comment: What vwrsion of a Windows

Comment: windows 7 64 bit

Comment: Correlation is not necessarily causation. Are you sure of the reason the machine is exhibiting this behavior. Your further posts in comments make it seem as if there is another problem.

Comment: You can wipe the temp directory all you want IF it causes a problem with an application then that applocation has a bug and it should be reported the temp directory isn't ised by OneDrive

Comment: Don't clear temp files that are newer than your current boot time/date stamp. The system shouldn't allow you to delete open files, but if it was something currently relevant to a running process, it may cause an issue.

Comment: well i use office 365 and every reboot i have to reenter the password for my onenote notebooks to sync, so it's not just skydrive/onedrive. but as you say it doesn't use the temp folder, and i'm inclined to believe that after using the resource monitor and seeing how there is no activity in the temp folder from those processes

Comment: @FiascoLabs I'm not clearing the files after reboot. The entire TEMP folder is being wiped when I shut off my PC. thus on the next reboot there is a fresh clean TEMP folder to start with

Comment: here's an update: i didn't reboot or clear the temp folder. and Box just randomly asked me to enter my password again out of nowhere

Comment: You have checked for viruses, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the temporary directories of those specific programs, and you're sure that that's the cause of your problems, a complicated but efficient solution to do what you want would be to automatically [generate symbolic links](https://superuser.com/a/608912/33758) from the folders of those programs in the ramdisk temp directory to a permanent folder on your HD. You could achieve that with a [.bat file](http://www.computerhope.com/batch.htm), and [use the Windows Task Scheduler](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7) to make it repeat the process on every logon.

Comment: symbolic links could work, thanks for suggesting that. however >However, one problem I am having is I cannot seem to find any files relating to OneDrive or Box in the temp folder even after I log in again.

Comment: You can [open the Windows resource monitor](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/open-resource-monitor) and then use the "Disc" tab to verify what files those programs access/create when you use them.

Comment: the resource monitor is nice, i didn't know it let you see what files each process is using. this is a nice security feature. i'm looking at it now and it doesn't look like BoxSync.exe is using the temp folder at all

Comment: Well, I don't even use those programs, so I can't offer further help. Try contacting the Box Sync support to be sure that there isn't anything else preventing it to store your passwords. 

By the way, I keep my browser cache and the files I save temporarily (like installers) in a SoftPerfect RAM Disk folder that is also deleted automatically when I log off. It's very lightweight and stable. I had also set it to keep the Windows cache folder, but since I had some troubles with it too because it's an essential part of Windows, I've decided not to use a ramdisk for it anymore.

Comment: storing browser cache in ramdisk sounds fun, how do i configure chromium to store it's stuff somewhere else? edit: i can just google that lol, thanks for the idea

Comment: I use Firefox. To change the cache folder of Chrome/Chromium, you'd need some tweak (like, again, a symbolic link): http://essayweb.net/miscellany/chrome.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Radeon RAMDisk uses image file to load its initial state. After reboot, enter OneDrive, etc. passwords, then Save current ramdrive state. Then all new reboots will start with some files in TEMP folder for necessary passwords.